# Find whether check boxes are checked inside a servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have several check box in a form I just wanna way to check whether they are checked or not .

If checked i need to store their id in the database(that i can do it ) . But my question is how to determine whether are checked or not instead of checking for each check box on at a time . **I need to check whether its checked or not inside a servlet.**

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Role Id<input type="text" name="roll_id"/><br>
Role Name<input type="text" name="roll_name"/><br>
Role Description<textarea name="roll_desc"></textarea><br>
<br>
<br>

Screen1<br>

tab1<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_view" value="s1_t1_view" >view<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_add" value="s1_t1_add" >add<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_edit" value="s1_t1_edit" >edit<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t1_delete" value="s1_t1_delete" >delete<br>

tab2<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_view" value="s1_t2_view" >view<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_add" value="s1_t2_add" >add<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_edit" value="s1_t2_edit" >edit<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s1_t2_delete" value="s1_t2_delete" >delete<br>



Screen2<br>

tab1<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_view" value="s2_t1_view" >view<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_add" value="s2_t1_add" >add<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_edit" value="s2_t1_edit" >edit<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t1_delete" value="s2_t1_delete" >delete<br>

tab2<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_view" value="s2_t2_view" >view<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_add" value="s2_t2_add" >add<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_edit" value="s2_t2_edit" >edit<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="s2_t2_delete" value="s2_t2_delete" >delete<br>
<input type="submit" name="sumbit" text="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

But in my code I have several check boxes . I need to hardcode that for every check box . Is there way so that i put it in a loop and check for all check boxes ?

Comment: If you need to use a groupe of checkbox, the `name` attribute must be the same for each grouped checkbox !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To be simple, you can use the `name` attribute to get the data since you are using different name for each checkbox.

In Servlet :

```
String[] s1_t1_view = request.getParameterValues("s1_t1_view");
String[] s1_t1_add = request.getParameterValues("s1_t1_add");
```

If you want to use group of checkbox to give the user a choice between multiple values, you will need to iterate over the group in the servlet. You can use this :

In HTML : (same name = same group)

```
<input type = "checkbox" name = "s1_t1" value = "s1_t2_view"   >View  <br>
<input type = "checkbox" name = "s1_t1" value = "s1_t2_add"    >Add   <br>
<input type = "checkbox" name = "s1_t1" value = "s1_t2_edit"   >Edit  <br>
<input type = "checkbox" name = "s1_t1" value = "s1_t2_delete" >Delete<br>
```

In Servlet :

```
String[] results = request.getParameterValues("s1_t1");
for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(results[i]); 
}
```

Comment: Yes this one helped . Thanks .

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
String[] checked = request.getParameterValues("checkboxName");
```

and then check the `checked` value

Comment: But in my code i have several check boxes . I need hardcode that for every check box . Is there way like so that i put it in a loop and check for all check boxes ?

Answer (score 0):

For me this one worked.

```
    String[] selecttype=request.getParameterValues("selectType");

//selectType is the name of checkbox in jsp page.
```

This will return selected checkbox values.

Comment: How different is this answer from other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Create hidden fields as

Now in your servlet as: String[] names = request.getParameterValues("checkbox");

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("/Desktop/sticker.txt"));
for(int i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if(i + 1 < names.length && names[i].equals(names[i+1])) {
        pw.write(names[i] + ",true\n");
        ++i;
    } else {
        pw.write(names[i]+",false\n");
    }

}
pw.close();
```